# Energy consumption optimization algorithm advice needed

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

I have an interesting task, which I can't conclude it's easy or hard.

The task as follows:

Given 12 integers representing monthly maximum kWh consumption from the previous year.
We need to determine where to set our monthly qouta for the next year corresponding months based on the following rules:

If we set the qouta to 1000 and our consumption will be 1000, than we pay 1000 kWh fee, if the consumption is only 800, but the qouta is 1000, we need to pay 1000 kWh, and we can't roll it to the next month.

If the qouta is 1000 and we consumed 1200, we need to pay 1600 kWh fee, because there is a 3* penalty on the remaining energy.

We can increase our qouta monthly.

We can decrease it once a year, at a fixed date,the fixed date set by the energy provider, so basically we need to determine once a year for example at October we lower a the qouta or not for the following months.
We can request operative month 3 times a year where the penalty on our overusage is only 1.3 instead of 3.

Based on these rules we need to determine when to increase or not our qouta, is a decrease needed at all, which months should get operative, to lower our penalty, when is worth pay the penalty, to lower the entire year cost.

A calculation can be start at any month, but we need to predict the following 12 months after that. We just need to consider the starting qouta for the first month, and calculate a good plan based on historical data(12 max numbers)

I'm thinking on some kind of brute force solution with backtracking, but I'm afraid the possibilities are too much when we have a bigger range to test out.

Thank you for your help finding the best approach for this problem.

Comment: Do you have any means of analysis for the input data, yet? Like how many spikes you have, how wide each of them is ... some statistical numbers like average, mean, standard deviation, etc from which you could derive some thresholds? Outside factors like planned high consumption (big customer on a spending spree in July, e.g.)? What's the probablity that if last year it 950, this year it's going to be 1050? (Was there an overall trend in consumption?)

Comment: What is the fee if the quota is `1000` and the consumption is `800`? Should we pay the quota (800) or just consumption (1000)?

Comment: We need to pay the consumption of 1000 in this case. We don't need to analyse trend at this point, only a good enough prediction needed based on the max kWhs of previous month's consumption.

Comment: Well if the trend is steep enough then the forecast could be too low, so I'd consider it, but that could also be done later on.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you want all numbers/decisions set at the start of the year or it's on a monthly basis? If it's on a monthly basis I assume you get a new consumption value at the end of each month that can be include in the decision for the next month... or?

Comment: This sounds like a very typical case for a multi-armed bandit algorithm

Comment: To me it's also unclear what the "fixed date" for a decrease means. Who sets the date?

Comment: Thanks for commenting on this. The fixed date set by the energy provider, so basically we need to determine once a year for example at October we lower a the qouta or not for the following months.

Comment: A calculation can be start at any month, but we need to predict the following 12 months after that. We just need to consider the starting qouta for the first month, and calculate a good plan based on historical data(12 max numbers)

Comment: Do you guys need more info on this matter?

Comment: You could edit the question and add any additional information that is essential for understanding/solving the problem. The [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) are not considered part of the question, and can be removed by the moderators.